# Npmで推移的依存パッケージをプルリクを含んだ状態で使用

Tags: npm

Npmでパッケージ管理をしています。
使っているパッケージが推移的に依存しているパッケージを、まだリリースされていないプルリクを含んだ状態で使いたいです。
package.jsonをどのように書けば良いでしょうか。